# How to create json object for html form using AngularJS?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am learning angularJS now a days. How can I create a json object for my given `html` form. I can do it with `jQuery`, but I need to do this in `AngularJS`, kindly let me know that how can I do [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/nj0dp3bw/) in angularJS and Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this specific to Angular? Are you using jQuery in your project? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661187/form-serialize-javascript-no-framework

Comment: @Roope, I need to create json object with AngularJS instead of with jQuery, is there any way to create with AngularJS only ?

Comment: @Dhana JQuery lite is built-in with AngularJS. So doing it with jQuery when in Angular universe won't harm.

Comment: @Dhana, you might be interested in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141035/angularjs-serialize-form-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better without serialize you can do like this using ng-model.

```js
var app = angular.module('demoApp', []);

app.controller('demoController', function($scope) {
  $scope.formData = {}
  $scope.serialize = function($event){
    console.log($scope.formData)
    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.formData))
    $event.preventDefault()
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">

<head>

  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" ></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="demoController">
  <h2>Form</h2>
  <form action="" method="post" id="formid" name="testForm">
    First Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="formData.Fname" maxlength="50" size="12" />
    <br/> Last Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="formData.Lname" maxlength="50" size="12" />
    <br/> Select a Level of Education:
    <br/>
    <select ng-model="formData.education">
      <option value="Jr.High">Jr.High</option>
      <option value="HighSchool">HighSchool</option>
      <option value="College">College</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" ng-click="serialize($event)" />
    </p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont see a need to serialize form data we can set a object in controller 
and add model as properties in to it.
Here is the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Rishii/pen/GZOMJK?editors=1010).

View :

```
<form name="contactForm" class="col-md-6" ng-app="app" ng-controller="bodyCtrl">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Firstname</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="simpleForm.first_name">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Lastname</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng- model="simpleForm.last_name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <select class="form-control" name="" id="" ng-options="option.value as option.label for option in educationOptions" ng-   model="simpleForm.education">
     </select>
  </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleShow()">Submit</button>
  <pre ng-hide="!show">
      <code>
     {{simpleForm|json}}
     </code>
  </pre>
```

Controller :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

 app.controller('bodyCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.show = false;
 $scope.simpleForm = {};
 $scope.educationOptions = [{
'label': 'Jr.High',
'value': 'Jr.High'
 }, {
'label': 'HighSchool',
'value': 'HighSchool'
 }, {
'label': 'College',
'value': 'College'
}]
 $scope.simpleForm.education = $scope.educationOptions[0].value;
 $scope.toggleShow = function() {
   $scope.show = !$scope.show
  }
})
```

You might want to refer [to this link for more on data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/how-does-data-binding-work-in-angularjs).And this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) if you are coming from jQuery background.